# F-score for model selection in e1071 package in R

Tags: r, svm

I am using svm classifier for multiple classes. So far i did not have a problem. The best method is calculated based on accuracy in training data. However I would like to select best method based on F score which is

```
F1 = 2 * Precision * Recall / Precision + Recall
```

I am guessing i have to use `error.fun` in `tune.control` but i do not know how to do it.

I know in caret package it is easy but i need to use e1071 package.

Any idea would be appreciated well.

Comment: try posting this on the Cross Validated, the numerical version of the stacks: http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can use the e1071 implementation of svm in caret by supplying the argument `method = "svmLinear2"` to `caret::train` then use the model selection tools within caret